# comparing characters in c++

Tags: c++, char

If I run my program, it doesn't compare the value entered after "Bitte Funktion waehlen" to `sin`, `cos` or `tan`. Instead, it always jumps directly to the `else` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace::std;

int funktions_wahl(char funktion, int genauigkeit)
{
    char sin;
    char cos;
    char tan;
    int x;
    if (funktion==sin) {
        cout << "sin von " << x << " =" << 2*x*genauigkeit; //Wie sin als fkt hier benutzen? 2x vorübergehend.
    }
    else if (funktion==cos) {
        cout << "cos von " << x << " =" << 4*x*genauigkeit; //Gleiches Spiel wie oben.
    }
    else if (funktion==tan) {
        cout << "tan von " << x << " =" << 8*x*genauigkeit; //Gleiches Spiel wie oben;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Keine gültige Variable eingegeben\r";
    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    char f;
    int g=0;
    cout << "Taschenrechner 1.0\r" << "Bitte Funktion eingeben: ";
    cin >> f;
    cout << "Genauigkeit wählen: ";
    cin >> g;
    funktions_wahl(f, g);
}
```

I don't understand why. Does someone has an advice for me?

Comment: Isn't "Funktionswahl" a noun? Why did you insert an underscore in between there?

Comment: Yes. I thought about that too. Since im very new to c++ do you have an advice to which I should change it? Char didnt work..

Comment: That's more of a readability's concern. Just call it `funktionswahl`. I mean, you don't write "Die Funktions Wahl" but "Die Funktionswahl", right? Writing programs in English is, at least for StackOverflow, better.

Comment: @cad: I'm a German native speaker, and reading German words in code makes me cringe. It's just so terribly wrong. I've never seen it in professional code in any company here in Austria, except of some really special domain-specific vocabulary. Still, the choice between `Funktionswahl`, `funktions_wahl`, `Funktions_Wahl` etc is irrelevant. The only almost universal naming convention in C++ is ALL_CAPS for macros and only for macros. Everything else is opinion-based.

Comment: @cad: By the way, both "Funktionswahl" and "Funktions-Wahl" are correct German words. The difference between the two is very subtle. That's why the OP was (grammatically) correct when he used an underscore.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I'm too. I wanted to note that too but I thought he probably writes this program for school (if not, my apologies), so that doesn't matter much. Regarding your second comment: oops, didn't know that. But frankly, who writes "Funktions-Wahl" nowadays?

Comment: @cad: When we took our first C class in the first semester at university (an Austrian university, that is), using German identifiers in your code would lead to lower grades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char sin;
char cos;
char tan;
int x;
if (funktion==sin) {
    cout << "sin von " << x << " =" << 2*x*genauigkeit;
```

You forgot to initialize `sin`, `cos`, `tan` and `x` and are therefore reading uninitialized memory.

You probably intended something like `char sin = 's';` and so on.

Comment: And likely `int x = genauigkeit;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you didn't initialize the variables `sin`, `cos` and `tan` (which should be constants actually), which leads to undefined behavior:

- For a debug build, the compiler may indeed execute step-by-step your program, and thus compare uninitialized, random numbers;
- For an optimized build, the compiler is likely to optimize away these comparisons between uninitialized local variables and only implement the error case (`cout << "Keine gültige Variable eingegeben\r";`).

To correct this, you should instead define and initialize these constants as follows:

```
const char sin = 's';
const char cos = 'c';
const char tan = 't';
```

**UPDATE**

To answer your updated question (how to consume "sin" rather than 's'), you simply need to change the types of your variables from `char` to `string`, and change the literals from char literals (between simple quotes) to string literals (between double quotes), as exemplified below:

```
string f;
...
const string sin = "sin";
const string cos = "cos";
const string tan = "tan";
```

Comment: There is no need to make them static.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

I changed it as you suggested. But still isn´t it possible to enter e.G sin instead of s ?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace::std;



int funktions_wahl(char funktion, int genauigkeit, int x)
 {
char sin='s';
char cos='c';
char tan='t';
if (funktion==sin) {
    cout << "sin von " << x << " =" << 2*x*genauigkeit << "\r"; //Wie sin als fkt hier benutzen? 2x vorübergehend.
}
else if (funktion==cos) {
    cout << "cos von " << x << " =" << 4*x*genauigkeit << "\r"; //Gleiches Spiel wie oben.
}
else if (funktion==tan) {
    cout << "tan von " << x << " =" << 8*x*genauigkeit << "\r"; //Gleiches Spiel wie oben;
}
else {
    cout << "Keine gültige Variable eingegeben\r";
}
return 0;
}





int main() {
char f;
int g=0;
int x=0;
cout << "Taschenrechner 1.0\r" << "Bitte Funktion eingeben: ";
cin >> f;
cout << "Genauigkeit wählen: ";
cin >> g;
cout << "x wählen: ";
cin >> x;
funktions_wahl(f, g, x);
```

Comment: No, `cin >> f`will only consume the first 's' in "sin". That will make the`cin >> g` misbehave. You can use `std::string` to read and compare words.

Comment: Firstly, because this is an update to your question, the best approach is to edit your question as follows: (1) start editing your question (2) go to the end of your question and append **UPDATE** (3) then append the updated question.